# Undo going too many steps in Blender 3.4

Tags: interface, edit-mode, pose-mode, object-mode

I have been having a problem recently where my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> undo has been going too far. Often I will hit undo once and blender will delete roughly an hour of work. It deletes objects, materials, keyframes in pose mode and anywhere else.

After this happens my undo history only has a grayed out "Original" with a circle next to it. My redo options are grayed out so I can't recover the work. Every time this happens I have to reload with my most recent save.

I have my undo steps set to 150 and undo memory limit at 0.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Hello. probably `Global Undo` is disabled in Preferences > System > Memory & Limits. See [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/system.html#memory-limits)

Answer (score 0):

Try recording a video of it and upload it so we can see your steps. If this happens often try to not only save your files, but save backups.

Comment: Blender autosaves every 2 minutes by default...